# Faunadb gives error on Paginate Error like "Ref or set expected, string provided"

Tags: faunadb

I am learning about FaunaDB and on running the following script in Fauna Shell I get the error:

```
Error: [
  {
    "position": [
      "map",
      "expr",
      "get"
    ],
    "code": "invalid argument",
    "description": "Ref or Set expected, String provided."
  }
]
```

Query I am trying to run:

`Map(Paginate(Match(Index("todo_tasks"))), Lambda(x => Get(x)))`

Comment: What are the `Values`  in your Index definition for "todo_tasks" ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all. I've figured it out. The problem was that the index I created was not returning the refs which is required by Get. Therefore, I created a new Index which returned the refs and used it instead and it worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Match is supposed to have two arguments. I think what's happening is that it is defaulting to matching against an empty string. You have to tell Fauna what you're Matching your index with. Have you tested your index? You can go to the fauna client and click on indexes. You should be able to select "string", "number" or "FQL" and enter a value that would return the document you're searching for.

But in order to properly determine what the second argument should be, you need to provide more information as to how your index is constructed for your todos. If the index is on a data type Todo, you need to provide a Ref to that Todo as your second argument in Match.